# Vue JS Pass Data From Parent To Child Of Child Of Child

Tags: vue.js, state, vue-props

In Vue.js, how to correctly pass data from parent component to a chain of multi level child components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. [Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)
2. [Event Bus](https://css-tricks.com/using-event-bus-to-share-props-between-vue-components/)
3. [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)
4. [Provide/Inject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html)

Find out more here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/data-components-vue-js/

Answer (score 2):

@RoboKozo listed some really great options for you, it just depends on what you're doing with the data.

If it's *static* data (*and you like to be modular*), you can always make use of mixins.

From the Vue.js docs:

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

### Example 1: Mixins

**File/Folder Setup:**

```
/src/mixins/defaultDataMixin.js // Call this whatever you want
```

**/src/mixins/defaultDataMixin.js:**

```
export const default defaultData {
    data() {
        return {
            property1: "Foo",
            property2: "Bar"
        }
    }
};
```

Now, on any component you want to have access to `property1` or `property2`, you can just import your mixin.

**/src/pages/MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ property1 }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    {{ property2 }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defaultData } from "@/mixins/defaultDataMixin"

export default {
    mixins: [defaultData],
}
</script>
```

### Example 2: Sharing data via Props & Emit

Props **down**, Emit **up**

Perhaps you return some data in a Parent component that you wish to pass down to be used in a child component. Props are a great way to do that!

**File/Folder Setup**

```
/src/pages/ParentComponent.vue
/src/components/ChildComponent.vue
```

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <child-component :defaultDataProp="defaultData" @emitted-text="helloWorld">
                    </child-component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defaultData } from "@/mixins/defaultDataMixin"
import ChildComponent from "@/components/ChildComponent.vue"

export default {
    mixins: [defaultData],
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            emittedText: "",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        helloWorld(e){
            this.emittedText = e;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ defaultDataProp }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button @click="emitData">Emit Data</button>
                </col>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        defaultDataProp: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            text: "Hello, world!"
        };
    },
    methods: {
        emitData() {
            this.$emit('emitted-text', this.text);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Cool, right?

These are just a couple of ways you can share data and functions between components.

### ** **Edit** **
Example 3: Vuex state + mapGetters

I just noticed you tagged this `state` as well, so I'm **assuming** you have [already installed](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#direct-download-cdn) and are using Vuex.

While it's not "passing" the data from parent to child directly, you could have the Parent component can mutate a state that a child component is watching.

Let's imagine you want to return the user information and then have access to that data across multiple components.

**File/Folder setup**:

```
/.env 
/src/main.js
/src/store/store.js
/src/store/modules/user.js
/src/mixins/defaultDataMixin.js
/src/util/api.js
/src/pages/ParentComponent.vue
/src/components/ChildComponent.vue
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { store } from "@/store/store";
// ... add whatever else you need to import and use

Vue.use(vuex); // but make sure Vue uses vuex

// Vue can "inject" the store into all child components
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store: store, // <-- provide the store to the vue instance
    // ..
});
```

**.env**:

```
VUE_APP_API_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8000'
```

**api.js**:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { store } from "@/store/store";

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
});

export default apiClient;
```

**user.js**:

```
import apiClient from "@/util/api"
import { store } from "../store"

const userModule = {
    state: () => ({
        user: {
            firstName: "",
        }
    }),
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, payload) {
            state.user = payload;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async loadUser({ commit, dispatch }) {
            try {
                const user = (await apiClient.get("/user")).data;
                commit("setUser", user); // mutate the vuex state
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch("logout");
            }
        },
        logout({ commit }) {
            commit("setUser", {});
        }
    },
    getters: {
        firstName: (state) => {
            return state.user.firstName;
        }
    }
   
};

export default userModule;
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import userModule from "@/store/modules/user"; // Grab our newly created module

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    userState: userModule,
  },
});
```

**defaultDataMixin.js**

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export const default defaultData {
    data() {
        return {
            property1: "Foo",
            property2: "Bar"
        }
    },
    // We can make use of mapGetters here 
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["firstName"]),
    }
};
```

Now, both Parent and Child have access to the centralized state and can mutate it. For example, let's call the `loadUser()` from the parent and watch for the state change on the child component.

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col" v-if="firstName != ''">
                    {{ firstName }}
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <button @click="mutateState">Click Me</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <child-component @emitted-text="helloWorld">
                    </child-component>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defaultData } from "@/mixins/defaultDataMixin"
import ChildComponent from "@/components/ChildComponent.vue"
export default {
    mixins: [defaultData],
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    },
    methods: {
        // our new method to mutate the user state 
        mutateState() {
            this.$store.dispatch("loadUser");
        },
        helloWorld(e){
            this.emittedText = e;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    {{ defaultData }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button @click="emitData">Emit Data</button>
                </col>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { defaultData } from "@/mixins/defaultDataMixin"

export default {
    mixins: [defaultData],
   
    data() {
        return {
            text: "Hello, world!"
        };
    },
    methods: {
        emitData() {
            this.$emit('emitted-text', this.text);
        }
    },
    // Let's watch for the user state to change 
    watch: {
        firstName(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log('[state] firstName state changed to: ', newValue);
            // Do whatever you want with that information 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```