# Vuex call function to vuejs file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuex

I've been trying to load all of my data when the time I log in. Currently, I've only managed to display data through the console through vuex file. I just want to achieve this because wherever it loads all data when login, it will easier for me to call every function on every page. The problem is how can I pass data to the vue js file? or I think the first step is to display it on vue devtools? It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!

"./store/modules/currentUser.js"

```
import axios from "axios";
const state = {
    transansportDrivers: [] 
};
const getters = {};
const actions = {
    loadEmployee({}){
        axios.post(BASE_URL + '/transportation/driver/autoComplete').then(response => {
            commit('setTransportDrivers', response.data)
            console.log(response.data); 
        });
    }
};
const mutations = {

    setTransportDrivers: (state, drivers) => {
        state.transansportDrivers= drivers;
    },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

*vuejs file* I want to display the result of response.data to this script but it doesn't work

[image]

```
<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            listdata:[]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        login() {
            this.$store.dispatch('currentUser/loadEmployee', this.listdata);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab 'transansportDrivers' from the store to make it available in your vue file. You use mapState for that

Comment: Thanks for your response but what it looks like? Honestly Im newbie in vuex

Comment: You'd have to import mapstate from vuex, like so: import {mapState} from 'vuex'. Then, inside the computed you include ...mapState(['transansportDrivers']). Then, it should be available in your vue file

Comment: Thanks for you response, is this what it looks like? I've import mapstate in index.js [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rion.png) in vuex folder and I called it as console in vue file  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBF6p.png) but it didn't work mapstate is undefined

Comment: Import it in the Vue instance/component where you would like the state to be available. In the above code, assuming you want it in the file that contains the script, you can do: <script>import {mapState} from 'vuex' export default { computed:{...mapState(['transansportDrivers'])}}</script>

Comment: I wrote an answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925084/vue-js-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-of-child-of-child/66995201#66995201). Perhaps it'll help point you in the right direction @ShainnahJane