# Pass data from parent component to child of child in Vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, web-applications

I am deperately searching for a way to pass data from a parent component to a child of the child component.
I know I can use props to do this like in this thread [Vue JS Pass Data From Parent To Child Of Child Of Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925084/vue-js-pass-data-from-parent-to-child-of-child-of-child)

But I only get it to work for the "next" child component and I get stuck for the second one.

My parent component:

```
<ResultBar :carbondata="realCarbonValues" />

data() {
return {
    realCarbonValues: {
        slabs: 20,
        beams: 0, 
        columns: 0,
        foundation: 0,
        core: 0
    }
};
```

My child component:

```
props: {
    carbondata:Object
},


console.log(this.carbondata.slabs)
```

Now, I can log the data in the console from by using the child component

But what do I have to do in the next child componet to pass the data correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending on what you are trying to do you can just pass it directly as prop again.

Parent:

`<Child :prop-i-wanna-pass-deeply="something" />`

Child:

`<GrandChild :props-i-wanna-pass-deeply-again="propsIWannaPassDeeply" />`

GrandChild:

`<div>{{ propsIWannaPassDeeplyAgain }} is now here</div>`

---

or just use `provide` and `inject` to avoid prop-drilling.

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#provide-inject

*Read the note about reactivity of provide/inject*.

Parent:

```
<Child /> <!-- no need to pass the prop -->

provide() {
  return {
    something: "fooAbc",
  }
}
```

Child:

`<GrandChild />`

GrandChild:

```
<div>{{ something }}</div>

inject: ['something']
```

Comment: thank you very much, and thx for calling it "IWannaPassDeeply" ;)
Ok I got it that I just have to pass it deeper, but my problem is how to define the props in this case for the child and grandchild component if I want to pass an object and not just a variable?

Comment: same as how you would define props for any components since there's only one way to define props. if you want to pass an object literal directly from the template then do `<Child :prop="{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }" />`